# Fabric Answers for OSX link error

Tags: macos, cocoapods, twitter-fabric

Tried to use just annonced `Answers` framework for OSX platform:

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Answers'
pod 'Crashlytics'

#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Answers/Answers.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Answers class]]];
```

And got bunch errors:

```
...
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CLSAnswersInviteEvent in:
/Users/k06a/Projects/UXMaterial/Pods/Answers/OSX/Answers.framework/Answers(CLSAnswersInviteEvent.o)
/Users/k06a/Projects/UXMaterial/Pods/Crashlytics/OSX/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSAnswersInviteEvent.o)
ld: 200 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thats because `Crashlytics` framework already contains `Answers` framework inside itself. You just need to do this:

Podfile:

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

Your AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Answers.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Answers class]]];
    ...
}
```

Comment: For swift only import Fabric and Crashlytics since the Answers object is included in Crashlytics :)